# How to fix ViewDoesNotExist at /admin/

Tags: django, admin

I have had an admin section working fine in my django project but all of a sudden it reports this error:

> ViewDoesNotExist at /admin/
>
> Could not import restaurants.views.question. View does not exist in module  restaurants.views.

The front-end is still working fine.

Not sure what change I made to cause this - how to fix it?

Comment: Could you add the code from restaurants.views?

Answer (score 2):

This is usually an indication that the view in question does not exist or is not accessible by the admin panel. Are you sure you imported it, or included it as necessary?

Comment: #from urls.py
>     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))

Comment: It has been working for the last 2 weeks all of a sudden today it gave this error message. I don't recall modifying any of the code for the urls, views, or admin.py

Comment: Does the view actually exist? Was it accidentally removed? The problem is very clearly that Django can't find the view in question. It has nothing to do with your admin URLs

Comment: there is no view in my views.py for admin, but I never had one to begin with. I only had admin in my urls and in the admin.py document

Comment: # admin.py
>from restaurants.models import Restaurant, Query 
>from django.contrib import admin


>class RestaurantAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you've created an error that relates to your `question` view, and that's what's breaking the admin (`Could not import restaurants.views.question`). It's not actually an error with admin, or a new bug in the body of the `restaurants.views` module.

My guess is that you've created a circular import - Look at the imports at the top of your `restaurants.views` module. Now check each module that you're importing from and look see if that module imports from `restaurants.views`.

If that doesn't show anything check all the imports in all the models that are imported into your `restaurants.views` module and look for something there.

I've seen this a few times since using class based views. Obviously the whole point of class based views is that they can be extended. This can lead to circular dependencies. Unless I've only got a couple of views in my app, I tend to split everything out of a single file and create a views directory -

```
my_app
    views
        __init__.py
        view1.py
        view2.py
        view3.py
```

Then add the following import statements to your `__init__.py` so everything works as before -

```
from view1 import View1
from view2 import View2
from view3 import View3
```

This allows you to have much fewer import statements at the top of each view module reducing the risk of a circular dependency.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer - I still haven't gotten it to work but I'll keep trying.